# java not loading jar file

Tags: java, minecraft

I am trying to install a Minecraft server but am having a problem on the few first commands, when I put "java - version" (into cmd) it then says (-) is an unrecognized option, then when I did
"java -jar server.jar" it said its an incompatible version because it was compiled with version 60 but my installation supports up to 52. i tried installing different versions but it didn't work. any suggestions?
the full error is:

````
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/minecraft/server/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 60.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source) ```
````

Comment: You have a space. It should be `java -version`. You can't run code compiled to a higher version of Java than your runtime. You have Java 8. *IT* has been compiled to Java 16

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)

Comment: If you read the Minecraft Server requirements page, says Java 16 is required. You'll need to uninstall Java 8 completely first